# Checking to see if an attribute equals a particular string in any of a list of objects

Tags: python

Each of these objects has an attribute `name`. I want to check to see if a particular string is contained within any of these objects' `name` attributes.

`[<bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf8649ef10>, <bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf863616d0>, < bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf863616d0>]`

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I tried the following:  `if any(x.name == "C" for x in instance[1].bouncyballs)`, where `bouncyballs` is the list, and C is the string I am trying to match.

Comment: you can edit your question and put the code in there. That is easier to read :)

Comment: Looks good. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers give you the answer using the track you were already using ('any'). If you would like to know in which ball object the specific name is found, you can use:

```
bouncyballs = [<bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf8649ef10>, <bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf863616d0>, < bouncy.ball object at 0x7fdf863616d0>]
C = 'string'

nameFound = False
for ball in bouncyballs:
    if ball.name == C:
        # Do what you like
        print('%s is in %s!' % (C, ball['name']))
        nameFound = True

print(nameFound)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check one time you can try the in operator together with a generator expression

```
if "pizza" in (ball.name for ball in balls): ...
```

If you are going to check a few times you may prepare a set/dict in advance:

```
balls_names = set(ball.name for ball in balls) #build a dict if you want to use the ball after it is found...
#much later in the code...
if "pizza" in balls: ...
```

The later approach will take more memory but will be faster since its a O(1) lookup

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there can be up to hundreds of bouncyballs I need to check the names of. That is why I'm asking for the most efficient.

Comment: @natab - just notice that you'll have to update the container if balls are added or removed. in any case you don't want to build the set/dict each time

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track using `any` and a generator expression

```
>>> class A:
...  def __init__(self,name):
...   self.name = name
... 
>>> a=A('bob')
>>> b=A('mike')
>>> c=A('lelsley')
>>> l=[a,b,c]
>>> any('mike' in x.name for x in l)
True
>>> any('xyz' in x.name for x in l)
False
```